# MFC Debug Assertion when using SetWindowPos function

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

When I try to run the program, I get a message "Debug Assertion Failed,~\MFC\winoccc.cpp Line 314.

These are my Message Handlers

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProjectMainDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB_MAIN, &CProjectMainDlg::OnSelchangeTabMain)
ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I'm trying to resize Wnd Items on a dialog.

```
void CProjectMainDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

LOG_TRACE(_T("ON_SIZE : nType=%u, cx=%u, cy=%u"), nType, cx, cy);

if (!m_bInitialized)
    return;

CRect cClientRect;
GetClientRect(cClientRect);

m_dlgCalculator.SetWindowPos(&CCalculator::wndBottom, cClientRect.left, cClientRect.top, 
cClientRect.Width(), cClientRect.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_DRAWFRAME);
}


m_tabSelection.DeleteAllItems();
m_tabSelection.InsertItem(0, _T("Calc"));
m_tabSelection.InsertItem(1, _T("Paint"));
m_tabSelection.InsertItem(2, _T("Image Test"));

CRect rect;
CRect rect_tab;
m_tabSelection.GetWindowRect(&rect_tab);    //Copies the dimension of tabSelection

CPoint point;       //TopLeft Poiintof TabConrol
point = rect_tab.TopLeft();

//Add Calculator to Tab
m_dlgCalculator.Create(IDD_DIALOG_CALCULATOR, &m_tabSelection); 
m_dlgCalculator.GetWindowRect(&rect);
m_dlgCalculator.MoveWindow(point.x, point.y, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
m_dlgCalculator.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

//Add Paint Board to Tab
m_dlgPaintBoard.Create(IDD_DIALOG_PAINTBOARD, &m_tabSelection);
m_dlgPaintBoard.GetWindowRect(&rect);       
m_dlgPaintBoard.MoveWindow(point.x, point.y, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
m_dlgPaintBoard.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);


//Add Image Test to Tab
m_dlgImageTest.Create(IDD_DIALOG_IMAGETEST, &m_tabSelection);
m_dlgImageTest.GetWindowRect(&rect);
m_dlgImageTest.MoveWindow(point.x, point.y, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
m_dlgImageTest.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

And this is the line where alert message pops up.

```
void CCalculator::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);


CRect cRect;
GetClientRect(cRect);

m_ResultList.SetWindowPos(NULL, cRect.left + 300, cRect.top , cRect.Width()/3, cRect.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

The last sentence is where I get the alert message. When I comment that line I don't get the message. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

This is my CCalculatorDlg.h file

```
class CCalculator : public CDialogEx
{
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CCalculator)

public:
CCalculator(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // 표준 생성자입니다.
virtual ~CCalculator();

// 대화 상자 데이터입니다.
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG_CALCULATOR };
#endif

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV 지원입니다.

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
afx_msg void OnClickedButton0();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton1();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton2();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton3();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton4();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton5();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton6();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton7();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton8();
afx_msg void OnClickedButton9();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonPlus();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonMinus();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonMultipy();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonDivide();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonCalculate();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonPoint();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonDelete();
afx_msg void OnClickedButtonReset();

protected:
CEdit           m_EditInput;        // 인풋
CListBox        m_ResultList;

CString         m_strInput;     
bool            m_bFirstValue;      // 첫번째값이 입력되었는지 확인하는 값
float           m_fValue1;          // 첫번째 계산 값
int             m_intMode;          // 어떤 계산을 할것인가 0 = 덧셈, 1= 뺄셈, 2는 곱셈 3은 나눗셈
bool            m_bNewCalc;
bool            m_bCalcEnable;

void            Calculate();        //계산을 수행
void            ResetCalculator();  //계산기 초기화
void            StartNewCalc();     //계산이후 인풋값 초기화


public:
afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
};
```

Comment: Click on the "Retry" button of the assertion window. This will break into the debugger and show you the relevant MFC source code which will hints of what has gone wrong. [Edit] and tell us more. There is also a lot of information missing, for example what is `m_ResultList` and how is it initialized? My guess is it isn't initialized at all.

Comment: I'm so confused using TabCtrl. My Calculator dialog is in MainDlg's tab control. I have no idea where to initialize since CalcDlg has no OnInit message handler. @Jabberwocky

Comment: [Edit] and tell us more about `m_ResultList` : what is it? Where is is declared? How is it initialitzed.

Comment: I initialized it in CCalculator Dialog header file. Just added header file @Jabberwocky

Comment: Do you understand how to debug a program? Are you proficient in C? Are you proficient in C++? Are you proficient in the Windows API? If the answer to any of those is "No", you're neither going to understand your issue, nor be able to select the correct answer.

Comment: @meseee don't describe your code but [edit] your question _show_ it. `CListBox m_ResultList;` in `CCalculatorDlg.h` doesn't initialize anything. Show your `CCalculator::DoDataExchange` implementation.

Comment: When is `m_bInitialized` set to `true`? I tend to compare `GetSafeHwnd()` against `nullptr` instead to ensure it is ready for me to do any processing. You need to step into your event handler by putting a breakpoint and then stepping through line by line to identify when the problem happens.